# In an Apache Wicket application, where do CSS files go?

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, wicket

I've been searching all over the Internet for a simple explanation as to which folder I would put my CSS files for my (eventual) web application to use?

However the resources I have come across don't contain the answer I need (they offer different locations to put them in).

I'm not using Spring, or JavaScript, just Java EE (building my web application in Eclipse), and Tomcat to run it.

Any help gratefully appreciated.

Comment: Wicket reference site gives several options. Please have a look. https://wicket.apache.org/guide/guide/resources.html

Answer (score 0):

They should be in

```
src/main/webapp/style
```